# NavigationTitle blink

Tags: ios, swift

If app is killed and user click on push notification app takes it directly to the respective screen(detail screen) but before pushing to the detail screen we push to the list screen.When user click on back button of detail screen navigation title of list screen comes empty for a sec then gets correctly.What could be the reason.

```
switch(model!.action[1].lowercased()){
          case "profile":
                    NotificationUtils.sharedInstance.moveToDirectoryModuleWithLTDS()    //Will shift to Directory module
                    NotificationUtils.sharedInstance.moveToLocationList(false)

                    NotificationUtils.sharedInstance.moveToLocation(Guid(locID),rightPanel: false, needAnimation: false) //Move to department detail screen with Info tab selected
                    hideLoader() //Will stop loading indicator
                    break
}

func moveToLocationList(_ animate: Bool = true) {
         hideNavigationTitle()   //This function is used to clear the back button title.
        let dropVC = DepartmentViewController(nibName: "DepartmentViewController", bundle: nil)
        dropVC.employeeGroupInfo = EmployeeGroupInfo.locationInfo
        self.pushWithDelayToVC(dropVC, animation: animate)
    }

 func pushWithDelayToVC(_ viewController:UIViewController,animation:Bool = true)
   {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    AppDelegate.removeUserProfileSetupScreens()

    self.removeComposer { () -> Void in
        UIUtils.pushViewWhenHideBottom((appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController!, anotherVC: viewController, needAnimation: animation)
        self.hideSidePanel()
    }
}

func removeComposer(_ completion: @escaping (() -> Void))
{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    if let selectedController = appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedViewController
    {
        if let selectNavController = selectedController as? UINavigationController
        {
            if let visibleController = selectNavController.visibleViewController
            {
                if (NSStringFromClass(type(of: visibleController)) == "MFMailComposeInternalViewController" || NSStringFromClass(type(of: visibleController)) == "CKSMSComposeController" || NSStringFromClass(type(of: visibleController)) == "PLUICameraViewController" || NSStringFromClass(type(of: visibleController)) == "UIAlertController")
                {
                    visibleController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: { () -> Void in
                        completion()
                        return
                    })
                }
                else
                {
                    completion()
                }
            }
            else { completion() }
        }
        else { completion()}
    }
    else { completion() }
}
```

And code of viewWillAppear is :

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if employeeGroupInfo == EmployeeGroupInfo.departmentInfo {
        UIUtils.setTitleFontWhiteOnNavigationController(viewCtrl: self, titleStr: AppMessage.EDByDepartment)
    } else if employeeGroupInfo == EmployeeGroupInfo.locationInfo {
        UIUtils.setTitleFontWhiteOnNavigationController(viewCtrl: self, titleStr: AppMessage.EDByLocation)
    } else if employeeGroupInfo == EmployeeGroupInfo.teamInfo {
        UIUtils.setTitleFontWhiteOnNavigationController(viewCtrl: self, titleStr: AppMessage.EDMoreByTeamsMob)
    }

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```

}

```
public class func setTitleFontWhiteOnNavigationController(viewCtrl: UIViewController, titleStr: String, needBorder: Bool = true,needTitleImage: Bool = false)
{
    viewCtrl.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
    viewCtrl.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    viewCtrl.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.LTColor()
    // Set navigation bar background color
    viewCtrl.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

    viewCtrl.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0),NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]

    if needTitleImage {
        setImageWithTitle(viewCtrl: viewCtrl,titleStr: titleStr)
    }
    else {
        viewCtrl.title = titleStr
    }
    if needBorder
    {
        //Used to hide shadow line in navigation bar by Nikhil
        viewCtrl.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        viewCtrl.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
    }
    else
    {
        //Used to hide shadow line in navigation bar by Nikhil
        viewCtrl.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        viewCtrl.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }

}
```

Comment: add your viewWillappear method

Comment: is it label in navigationBar's title ?

Comment: No simply setting viewcontroller.title

Comment: set title in view did load

Comment: your code is very messy to understand try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20537264/3901620

Comment: I am setting title in viewDidLoad as well.